# Power Apps print screen to PDF using power automate (No HTML)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to save a full screen (Power Apps portrait print screen), in SharePoint list.

I had seen many solutions which us HTML with power Automate, but in my case, it is all label controls Images and multi DataGrid.

Is there a way to save the screen as is, to SharePoint list?

One solution for it, but it does not support Arabi as well:

there is shorter code to make the same using below:

```
With(
   {wPDF: PDF(SecreenName)},
   Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
      "hajjaj@hotmail.com",
      "Subject here",
      "Body here",
      {
         Attachments: 
        {
            Name: "PDFFileName.pdf",
            ContentBytes: wPDF
        }
     }
  )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried using Print function in Power Apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-print?

Comment: yes, but I need to save it to SharePoint instead of printing and asve as PDF then upload to  it.

Comment: Check my answer given below. You can generate PDF object and pass it to power automate to save it to your SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Print()** function in Power Apps to generate the PDF of your Power Apps screen.

Then you can pass it to Power automate flow to save it as a PDF file in your SharePoint site.

Check this Microsoft official documentation for this function: [Print() function in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-print)

Check this tutorial which shows how to generate PDF from Power Apps and save it in SharePoint site using Power Automate:

[PowerApps - PDF function to Generate & Save PDF in OneDrive/SharePoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4uwhRXkuU4)

Comment: it partially works but there is issue with this way that is not supporting any other language other than English, there was some Arabic on my screen and could not make it. :'(

Comment: I think that is the limitation with Microsoft Power Platform. Even if you try to convert HTML content with other languages to PDF using Power automate flow, it will not work for you using standard actions.

Comment: there is shorter code to make the same using below : 

With(
   {wPDF: PDF(SecreenName)},
   Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
      "hajjaj@hotmail.com",
      "Subject here",
   "Body here",
      {
         Attachments: 
        {
            Name: "PDFFileName.pdf",
            ContentBytes: wPDF
        }
     }
  )
)

Comment: This is to the send PDF file as email attachment. As per your above responses, I thought you wanted to upload it to SharePoint :)

Comment: ye, You are right.